# iPhone:API for creating Active exchange mailbox?

Tags: iphone

I want to develop an ActiveSync Exchange Mailbox. Is there an API support to create active sync mailbox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft detail the [active sync http protocol here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299446.aspx).

As far as I'm aware there aren't any publicly available library's to harness it in objective-c so you might have to roll your own.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. But i see Apple has already included this in iOS SDK. http://www.geekzone.co.nz/content.asp?contentid=7674 But i want to know what are the APIs and stuff i can use?

Comment: The MDM api program is seperate to the iOS developer program and much, much harder to get access too apparently - http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=13127507